# pg_restore tells schema "test" already exists but it isn't actually

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, pg-restore

When restoring a dump like this:

```
pg_restore --clean --create --exit-on-error --dbname=test test.tar
```

these error messages got printed out:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 21; 2615 80924 SCHEMA test test
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "test" already exists
Command was: CREATE SCHEMA test;
```

but when:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;
```

these got printed out

```
schema_name     
--------------------
pg_toast
pg_temp_1
pg_toast_temp_1
pg_catalog
public
information_schema
```

It seems like schema "test" doesn't exist yet,why do I got this kind of error?

Comment: `schemata` may hide schemas if you're not superuser. Also postgres version is missing. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-schemata.html

Answer (score 2):

What OS, which version of postgres dump was made, restored to same version?

Read [this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90258/pg-restore-archiver-db-could-not-execute-query-error-schema-public-alre), maybe it will help.

It states that there are some trivial issues with the `--clean` parameter, 
and you probably should try to create database manually and restore to it without
the create and clean options.